# Security issues of compiling against older JDKs

Tags: java, security

Are there any known security issues with compiling against an older JDK?  For instance lets say Oracle decides to change something in one of their implementations that was to close a security vulnerability.  If we compile against the older JDK would we still be vulnerable?

***EDIT***

We are running against JDK 6 and we compile against Java 5, which is the crux of the issue I was attempting to get at for any one else whom sees this question.  For the sake of completeness lets say that in the ant build we target 1.5

***EDIT 2***

Additionally there is the issue of calls in the application that potentially have private APIs/implementations that are not directly accessed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aside from some very hypothetical niche situation that hasn't ever happened yet, the only thing that matters is the version with which the application is executed.

I don't think there are any known security issues that have been "fixed" with @deprecated, because that wouldn't really be appropriate.

There are two issues at play here:
1) You can have your Java compiler produce binaries that are binary compatible with older versions. That affects the language features available to you.

2) You can compile against the Java system libraries of an older version, and that will affect what methods/classes are available, as they are always adding new ones.

But neither of these affects the security of your application. What matters is the runtime version with which the application is executed.

Observe that security problems are fixed between updates, not the major versions, which introduce changes in the language itself. For example, Java 6 is currently at update 21. Java 6 update 19 fixed stuff that was vulnerable in Java 6 update 18.

When Java 6 update 19 was released, updates were released for Java 1.5 and Java 1.4, to fix the same issues in Java 1.5 (update 24) and Java 1.4 (update 26). See the security baseline table here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u19-141078.html

Comment: this does seem to be the most complete answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you compile against JDK 1.5:

- Users that are using JRE 1.5 will be vulnerable
- Users that are using JRE 1.6 will not be vulnerable

The application will run using the libraries of the users's runtime.  Since the vulnerabilities are fixed in Oracle's library, which is now being called by your application, the security vulnerability will be alleviated.

However, since you compile against 1.5, your users will be able to use 1.5.  Do anything you can to avoid the vulnerability; if you can't avoid it, detect the JRE version at startup and issue an alert if apporpriate.

Comment: Good to know, how would it be possible to audit the HP version of the 1.5 JDK to ensure that the system will function as expected and to ensure that the issues that the Oracle supported Java closed are not present in the HP version?

Comment: If you're concerned with a specific vulnerability, make a test case against it.  The vulnerability notice should say what the problem is, and in many cases will include a code sample to exploit it.  Run that against your program running on HP, and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

If Oracle changes an *API* (not an implementation) to promote security, they will probably add an `@Deprecated` annotation but preserve backward compatibility for some time. The annotation will trigger a warning in a newer compiler, but not in yours, and not in the compiled program. (Unless Oracle decides to throw an exception or log a message from the deprecated method.)

Comment: I will rephrase my question to point to implementation instead of API.  Even though it is in reference to potentially private APIs

Answer (score 0):

I would say that those unfixed vulnerabilities are still there, and you and your app are still at risk.

It'd be the same issue as running with an old, unpatched OS or browser.

It's a good incentive to migrate up to newer JVMs.

Comment: I think I may have been a little unclear in my explanation, please see my edits.  This question comes to mind as there exists a multiplatform application that utilizes hpux wherein that vendor still supports java 1.5