# From a security standpoint, it is ok to build target an application to java 1.6, but using 1.7 and deploy to run on the jre7?

Tags: java, security, compatibility, java-7, jdk6

My question has *sort of* been answered, however I was wondering if there was any specific Oracle documentation confirming that this is not a problem.

related stackoverflow threads:
[Security issues of compiling against older JDKs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846237/security-issues-of-compiling-against-older-jdks)

[Is Java byte code compiled in JDK 6 and runs on JDK7 open to vulnerability fixed in JDK 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364418/is-java-byte-code-compiled-in-jdk-6-and-runs-on-jdk7-open-to-vulnerability-fixed?rq=1)

Comment: You can leverage the capability of several Java IDE's that allow you to specify the compiler language level to a lower JDK, thus giving you the strict validation against an older JDK while still maintaining the capability of the newer JDK. I can't see why this would inherently cause an issue because you're targeting the same version of the JRE as the JDK you've used to build

Comment: Just don't do it. The ugly hacks with using bootclasspath is much more complicated to cleanly compile against an older target environment. So why bother... (and this is indepentend from security concerns).

Comment: It is far simpler to target 1.7 if that is how you intend to run it.  If you want 1.6 and 1.7 support, just use 1.6.

Comment: Does anyone know of any documentation regarding this?